# deSolve ODE Not Working with Differential Equations (Calculates NA)

Tags: r, ode, differential-equations

I have been using method `deSolve::ode45` which has been working until I made a few necessary changes to my equations. Does anyone know why the ODE solver is not working? I have tried running with `ode45` as well as the default `ode` method and neither work. Please let me know if any further explanation would be helpful.

I have checked over the differential equations and I am confident they are correct.

The equations used are as follows:

```r
CCHFModel = function(t,x,params)
{
  # get SIR values
  SH <- x[1]
  EH <- x[2]
  IA <- x[3]
  IS <- x[4]
  RH <- x[5]
  ST <- x[6]
  IT <- x[7]
  SC <- x[9]
  IC <- x[10]
  RC <- x[11]
  
  # Load values ----
  
  # Beta values
  betaHHA = params["betaHHA"]
  betaHHS = params["betaHHS"]
  betaTH = params["betaTH"]
  betaCH = params["betaCH"]
  betaTC = params["betaTC"]
  betaCT = params["betaCT"]
  betaTT = params["betaTT"]
  
  # Gamma value
  gamma = params["gamma"]
  
  # death rates
  muH = params["muH"]
  muT = params["muT"]
  muC = params["muC"]
  
  # birth rates
  piH  = params["piH"]
  piT = params["piT"]
  piC = params["piC"]
  
  # incubation
  deltaHS = params["deltaHS"]
  deltaHA = params["deltaHA"]
  
  # recovery rate
  alphaA = params["alphaA"]
  alphaS = params["alphaS"]
  alphaC = params["alphaC"]
  
  
  # total population
  NH = (SH + IA + IS + EH + RH) + (piH * SH) - (muH * SH)
  NT = (ST + IT) +  (piT * ST) - (muT * ST)
  NC = (SC + IC + RC) +  (piC * SC) - (muH * SC)
  
  # tick carrying Capacity 
  # KT = NC * 130 # 130 ticks per carrier max
  
  #computations ----
  dSHdt <- (piH * NH) - (betaHHA * IA + betaHHS * IS + betaCH * IC + betaTH * IT)*(SH/NH) - (muH * SH)
  dEHdt <- (betaHHA * IA + betaHHS * IS + betaCH * IC + betaTH * IT)*(SH/NH) - ((deltaHA + muH)*EH)
  dIAdt <- (deltaHA * EH) - ((alphaA + muH + deltaHS) * IA)
  dISdt <- (deltaHS * IA) - ((alphaS + muH + gamma) * IS)
  dRHdt <- alphaA * IA + alphaS * IS - muH*RH
  dSTdt <- (piT * NT) - (betaTT *  IT + betaCT * IC)*(ST/NT) - (muT * ST)
  dITdt <- (betaTT * IT + betaCT *  IC)*(ST/NT) - (muT * IT)
  dSCdt <- (piC * NC) - (betaTC * IT)*(SC/NC) - (muC * SC)
  dICdt <- (betaTC * IT)*(SC/NC) - ((alphaC +muC) * IC)
  dRCdt <- (alphaC * IC) - (muC * RC)
  
  # return results
  list(c(dSHdt, dEHdt, dIAdt, dISdt, dRHdt, dSTdt, dITdt, dSCdt, dICdt, dRCdt))
}
```

I run the ODE solver using:

```r
defaultParms = c(betaHHA = .0413,  
                 betaHHS = .0413,
                 betaTH = .2891, 
                 betaCH = .0826, 
                 betaTC = (1/365), 
                 betaCT = 59/365, 
                 betaTT = ((1/(365 * 2)) * .04) * 280,
                 gamma = 1/10, 
                 muH = (1/(365 * 73)), 
                 muT = (1/(365 * 2)),
                 muC = (1/(11 * 365)), 
                 piH = 1.25/(73 * 365), 
                 piT =  4.5/730,
                 piC = 1/(11 * 365),
                 deltaHS = 1/3, 
                 deltaHA = 1/2, 
                 alphaA = 1/17, 
                 alphaS = 1/17, 
                 alphaC = 1/7) 
# time to start solution 
t = seq(from = 0, to = 365, by = 0.1)

#initialize initial conditions
initialConditions = c(SH = 10000, EH = 5, IA = 5, IS = 10, RH = 2, ST = 80000, IT = 50, SC = 30000, IC = 5, RC = 1)

dataSet = ode(y = initialConditions, times = t, func = CCHFModel, parms = defaultParms)%>%
  as.data.frame()
```

After running this all the output following the initial conditions is NA.

Comment: can you please make this  easier to reproduce by (1) stating the parameter vectors you're using (as R code); (2) giving us the gradient function as a working function (rather than a code chunk), (3) posting your results as text rather than a screenshot (or, in this case it's probably sufficient to say just "all output after time 0 is `NA`) ...

Comment: A good first check is to run your gradient function with the state set equal to the starting conditions and make sure that all elements of the computed gradient vector are finite (and not `NA` or `NaN`)

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you for your suggestions! Please let me know if my changes are satisfactory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is due to a typo - you misnumbered the translation of input values in the first section of your code (i.e., you skipped `x[8]`. I will go through two (hopefully) useful exercises, first explaining how I debugged this and then showing how to rewrite your function to make it less error-prone ...

### debugging

1. Try running the gradient function for `t=0`, `x=<initial conditions>`:

```
CCHFModel(0,initialConditions, defaultParms)
##          piH      betaHHA      deltaHA      deltaHS       alphaA          piT 
## -15.02882327  12.62349834   0.53902803   0.07805607   0.88227788 385.31052332 
##       betaTT          piC       betaTC       alphaC 
##   0.85526763           NA           NA           NA
```

Hmm, we already see we have a problem. Why are the last three elements of the computed gradients `NA`?

2. add `browser()` near the end of the function (before the `dsCdt <- ...` line) so we can take a closer look. Redefine the function, and try computing the gradient again.
3. When we get there and print out some of the quantities involved in the computation we see that both `NC` and `RC` are `NA` ... we can also see that an `NA` value of `RC` will cause `NC` to be `NA`, so let's check the definition of `RC` ...
4. aha! `RC` is defined as `x[11]`, but `length(initialConditions)` is only 10 ... and a closer look shows that we missed `x[8]`. Redefining properly gives non-`NA` values throughout (I don't know if they're *correct*, but at least they're not `NA`).

### error-proofing (1)

Although using `[]` or `[[]]` to extract elements of a vector usually give equivalent answers, **you should always use `[[]]` when you want to extract a single element (scalar) from a vector**. Here's why:

```
initialConditions[11]  ## NA
initialConditions[[11]] ## Error in x[[11]] : subscript out of bounds
```

If you use `[]`, the `NA` propagates through your code and you have to hunt down the original source. If you use `[[]]`, R fails right away and tells you where the problem is. An additional benefit is that `[]` propagates the names of the vector elements in a way that doesn't usually make sense (take a look at the names of the output in "debugging/1" above ...)

### error-proofing (2)

You can avoid all of the tedious and error-prone unpacking of the parameter and state vectors by replacing the unpacking code (everything before the computation of total populations) with

```
comb <- c(as.list(x), as.list(params))
attach(comb)
on.exit(detach(comb))
```

Provided that your parameter and state vectors are properly named (and there are no names that overlap between them), this will create a named list and allow looking up of the elements by name within your function; `on.exit(detach(comb))` makes sure that everything gets cleaned up properly at the end. (You will see recommendations to use `with()` to do this; I prefer the strategy here because it makes debugging within the function [if necessary] easier. But as @tpetzoldt notes in comments, you should **always** pair `attach(...)` with `on.exit(detach(...))`; otherwise things get very confusing and messy ...)

At the end of the function I would use

```
g <- c(dSHdt, dEHdt, dIAdt, dISdt, dRHdt, dSTdt, dITdt, dSCdt, dICdt, dRCdt)
names(g) <- names(x)
list(g)
```

to make sure the gradient vector is properly labeled, which makes troubleshooting easier.

Comment: Thank you so much, this response was extremely useful and I will be using your techniques for future debugging. Thank you again.

Comment: Thank you, Ben, excellent (as always). I will put your explanation to my favorite list of solutions and share it with my students. I stumbled somewhat over the recommendation using `attach`, but I agree that it could make debugging easier. But, we both know that it **extremely important** to use `on.exit(detach(....))`. If one forgets this and the vector is not detached (e.g. due to an error), simulation will get extremely slow and other strange things will occur.